# insert into where not exists in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I need the hive syntax for this equivalent in ansi sql

```
insert into tablea
(id)
select id 
from tableb
where id not in (select id from tablea)
```

so tablea contains no duplicates and only new ids from tableb are inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left outer join with a filter that the tableA.id is null:

```
insert overwrite into tableA (id)
select b.id from tableB b left outer join tableA a
 on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null
```