# How to use NOT IN in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Suppose I have 2 tables as shown below. Now, if I want to achieve result which sql will give using, `insert into B where id not in(select id from A)` 
which will insert `3 George` in Table B.

How to implement this in hive?

Table A

```
id  name      
1   Rahul     
2   Keshav    
3   George
```

Table B

```
id  name      
1   Rahul     
2   Keshav    
4   Yogesh
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951703/insert-into-where-not-exists-in-hive) is a very good reference.

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880124/hive-command-to-execute-not-in-clause

Comment: Philantrovert,arcticwhite thank you I understood as reffered by philantrovert it can be done with left outer join.

Comment: @arcticwhite - This answer is outdated.

Comment: @philantrovert - This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**NOT IN** in the WHERE clause with uncorrelated subqueries is [supported since Hive 0.13](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784) which was released more than 3 years ago, on 21 April, 2014.

```
select * from A where id not in (select id from B where id is not null);
```

---

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  3 | George |
+----+--------+
```

On earlier versions the column of the outer table should be qualified with the table name/alias.

```
hive> select * from A where id not in (select id from B where id is not null);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 1:22 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'id': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.
```

---

```
hive> select * from A where A.id not in (select id from B where id is not null);
OK
3   George
```

P.s.
When using **NOT IN** you should add `is not null` to the inner query, unless you are 100% sure that the relevant column does not contain null values.
One null value is enough to cause your query to return no results.

Comment: Hi Dudu, can you elaborate on the `is not null` issue?

Comment: @Amir, the SQL standard treats `x not in (a,b,c)` as `x<>a and x<>b and x<>c`. If for example c is NULL then `x<>c` is UNKNOWN, therefore the whole expression is UNKNOWN. UNKNOWN is treated as FALSE. That means that the query is not going to return any rows no matter what `x` value is.