# Alternative to Hive Query with NOT IN clause

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, notin

I have the following set of hive tables :

```sql
create table image_additions (
    customer_id STRING,
    image_key STRING,
    image_size STRING
);
create table image_removals (
   customer_id STRING,
   image_key STRING,
   image_size STRING
);
create table images_stored (
   customer_id STRING,
   image_key STRING,
   image_size STRING
);
```

And I want to run an insert from a query like the following :

```sql
insert into images_stored
select ia.customer_id, 
       ia.image_key, 
       ia.image_size 
from image_additions ia 
where ia.image_key not in 
       (select ir.image_key from image_removals ir);
```

This produces a cartesian product, and hive does not allow me to run it.
How can I do this, using an alternative query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880124/hive-command-to-execute-not-in-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714625/how-to-use-not-in-in-hive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using left join + where is null;

```
insert into images_stored
select ia.customer_id, 
       ia.image_key, 
       ia.image_size 
from image_additions ia 
     left join image_removals ir on ia.image_key=ir.image_key 
where ir.image_key is null;
```

Using not exists:

```
insert into images_stored
select ia.customer_id, 
       ia.image_key, 
       ia.image_size 
from image_additions ia  
where not exists (select 1 from image_removals ir where ia.image_key=ir.image_key);
```

Comment: Yes easy left join with NULL query does it (leftjoin also your name, nice dog)

Comment: Tried both, and they took about the same time. Thanks a lot for your help.